# driver for cudy wu1300s not building

Tags: drivers, kernel, make

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, my kernel version is 5.15.0-56-generic, and, I follow the guide exactly up to that point (like, two steps, but still), but then when I go to run sudo make, it doesn't build, I got the linux headers for this kernel version (or at least, the terminal says I did), but it still won't work.
This is the error whenever I make:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/build M=/root/mailmain/project/rtl88x2bu_linux  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:2378: modules] Error 2
```

and this is what it said when I went to get the Linux headers:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic is already the newest version (5.15.0-56.62).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do 'make clean', then install the driver on the GitHub below.

[GitHub - RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver: Realtek RTL88x2BU WiFi USB Driver for Linux](https://github.com/Rincat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver)

I hope it will help to solve the issue.